# Queue system php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a web application, and it's running on a free, slow webserver.  I'm trying to figure out how I can show the user a "your request is waiting" page while my application fetches the data.  My application is a facebook app, running off the graph API.

The graph API is really slow (10 seconds, when getting 300 posts from a user's feed) and then, of course parsing takes a long time too.  This is a bottleneck in my application and I'm not sure how to fix it (if it's just facebook's fault or mine).  I've been looking into fql but apparently it's the same as or slower than the graph API (because it is the graph API)

Comment: "then, of course parsing takes a long time too" --- parsing of what? Of 300 posts?

Comment: I'm filtering the 30, 000 rows of news feed data to only show statuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The graph API is really slow (10 seconds, when getting 300 posts from a user's feed)
>
> I'm filtering the 30, 000 rows of news feed data to only show statuses.
> [from comments]

Now what order of magnitude is the correct one – are we talking about reading hundreds or 10-thousands of posts at a time actually?

> I've been looking into fql but apparently it's the same as or slower than the graph API

You have not looked careful … FQL offers you the ability to filter the [`stream` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) by `type`of post – `… WHERE type = '46'` will only give you status updates.

Comment: Well, I "ask" Facebook for 300 posts, but I get 30, 000 rows of metadata (including the posts).  The fql query you suggested looks interesting, I'll give it a shot today!

Comment: Whoa.  That's 64 times faster than my previous implementation!

Answer (score -1):

A couple of suggestions (both client-side):

1. [jQuery and a progress bar](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-progress-bar-with-javascript/)
2. [Web workers](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2011/02/web-workers-part-2-using-jquery-deferred/)

Hope that helps